# Unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_FUNCTION 4

Tags: php, syntax-error, parse-error, php-parse-error

I keep getting the following error in PHP:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$date' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in your code on line 3

With the following code:

```
<?php
 require("/edconfig.php");
 class EasyDevop{
  $date = new DateTime();
  $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
  function dataLog($dataLog=""){
   file_put_contents($fileLog, $dataLog);
  }
  function newPage($filedirnametype=""){
   if(!file_exists($filedirnametype)){
    $handleFile = fopen($filedirnametype, "w");
    dataLog($filedirnametype."; ".$date."\n");
   } else{
    echo "<b>Unable to create your page! It possibly already exists.</b>";
   }
  }
 }
?>
```

And I have tried everything, but I simply can't get it fixed. Can anyone please help me?

**I'm new to PHP OOP.**

Comment: Your class syntax isn't even close to correct. Almost the entire thing is one big error. You need to read up on how classes work in PHP and rewrite it.

Comment: @JohnConde Should I then ask on CodeReview?

Comment: No. This code is not functional code therefore there is nothing to review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at object-orientated programming in the official PHP documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php